# ¿Es posible reutilizar un Thread (Hilo)?

Tags: java

Un Thread(Hilo) muere cuando su método run( ) termina. Mi duda es: ¿El hecho de que el hilo muera, quiere decir que el objeto Thread se vuelva null?

¿es posible reutilizar un hilo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vamos a resolver las dudas una a una.

Primero, aclarar sobre esto:

> Un Thread(Hilo) muere cuando su método run( ) termina

Una instancia de la clase `Thread` *representa*, dentro del lenguaje de programación, a un *hilo de ejecución*. Pero el *hilo de ejecución* como tal no es propio del lenguaje de programación, sino es un artefacto del sistema operativo.

Es el sistema operativo quién le da *vida* al hilo y se encarga de *ejecutarlo*.

La clase `Thread` de java encapsula lo necesario para gestionar este artefacto a bajo nivel con el sistema operativo. Cuándo el método `run()` termina, ese hilo de ejecución *muere* en el sistema operativo, y no hay nada que hacer al respecto. Simplemente terminó.

> ¿El hecho de que el hilo muera, quiere decir que el objeto Thread se vuelva null?

No. Si has guardado una referencia a la instancia de `Thread` esta seguirá teniendo valor hasta que manualmente se le asigne `null` o salga de contexto.

> ¿es posible reutilizar un hilo?

En el sistema operativo, no lo es. Una instancia de `Thread` creada en java, tampoco.

Sin embargo, en java, así como en otros lenguajes de alto nivel, hay abstracciones que nos permiten tener uno o varios *hilos de ejecución* ya *creados* en el sistema operativo y asignarles distintos trabajos. Esto, para evitar el tiempo que conlleva la creación y terminación de hilos y optimizar procesos. Estos *hilos* podríamos decir que si que son re-utilizables, aunque técnicamente hablando solo inician y terminan una vez, pero la abstracción nos permite asignares *tareas* que pueden iniciar y terminar varias veces durante su vida.

Estas abstracciones son conocidas en inglés como ***thread pools***. En java, podrías buscar el término en google para informarte. Yo he encontrado este enlace en una búsqueda rápida (en inglés):

[Introduction to Thread pools in java](https://www.baeldung.com/thread-pool-java-and-guava)

Answer (score 1):

Un `Thread` termina cuando el método `run()` termina.

Una vez terminado la variable `Thread` no queda automáticamente en `null`, pero igualmente no se puede usar de nuevo dado que tirá `java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException`.

Podés usar `isAlive()` para saber si todavía está corriendo.